# AIR iOS application window is tiny

Tags: ios, flash, air

I'm having a problem previewing my ios app on my computer (running Windows 7). The app is made for iPad and has a resolution of 1024x768. But when I preview it (export as a swf as opposed to play the ipa on my iPad) the window that displays it is tiny (I think exactly half the size of the app) and cannot be resized.

This causes the app to be twice as small as it should be, which is untestable. If I listen for Event.RESIZE and set the stage.scaleMode to NO_SCALE, then the app remains 1024 x 768 but only the corner of it is displayed in the tiny window (also untestable).

I'm having a heck of a time finding a solution for this. Does anyone know how to make the swf window larger??

Thanks,

Tabby

Comment: In case you are testing the application yourself, I'd rather debug the app instead of exporting it as a SWF. ADL should give you the correct stage size.

Comment: Yes, in the end I had to learn how to use the Terminal to open the app with ADL. It worked very nicely on the Mac, haven't been able to test on my laptop yet. But learning all that was a whole challenge on its own!